# Can a community wiki-ed post be reverted?

Tags: support, status-completed, community-wiki

You see, [there's this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12601/pokemon-generation-iv-platinum-pearl-diamond-whats-new-since-gameboy-versio/12604#12604) I posted. And I edited it adding new content. A lot. So much, in fact, that it turned into a community wiki answer. Now, this request may be a bit strange, but is it possible for a community wiki post to be turned back into a normal post? I suppose this is slightly related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14397/dont-have-your-edits-to-posts-you-own-contribute-towards-making-the-post-commun) on Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes*, [a moderator *can* revert CW status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373).

This is an automatically triggered anti-abuse measure, so it's up to a mod to decide whether the edits were abusive or not. Make a moderator flag.

Comment: Adding this comment for posterity so that people don't see this deletion as *complete* abuse of authority - [I had permission to do it ♪](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/conversation/grace-pulls-a-finishing-move)

Comment: @Grace Undeleted ♫